# SQL how to concat table Valued Parameter to Values in an existing table on ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a TVP like below that I get from my code

```
 @texts as tvpnewtext readonly

 ID    Name      Text
 1     Mike      New Text
 2     Mike      New Text
 3     Mike      New Text
```

It contains an ID  a name and a text column.

I have an existing table that holds texts in my database.

```
 ID    Name      Text
 1     John      OLD Text
 2     John      OLD Text
 3     John      OLD Text
```

I want to update my old table to look like so:

```
 ID    Name      Text
 1     Mike      OLD Text New Text
 2     Mike      OLD Text New Text
 3     Mike      OLD Text New Text
```

Any help.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
UPDATE C
SET T.Text = T.Text + C.Text
FROM @texts         T
JOIN CurrentTable   C   ON T.ID = C.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be accomplished with a `MERGE`, I believe.  The `WHEN MATCHED BY SOURCE` clause would look like this:

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET S.NAME = T.NAME
,S.TEXT = S.TEXT + ' ' + T.TEXT
```

Comment: This is a good respond too. however Mark was first responding. Thanks

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper No problem.  I figured you wanted to change the Name as well since that is what you show in the expected results, which he didn't include.